# How to use variables from a class in a switch button

Tags: java, android

I am writing a very simple piece of code in android studio to just tell me what I will get paid every week because why not. Anyway I added an "overtime" switch button on it and I am not quite sure how to use the variables from MainActivity in the switch statement. `Variable 'hoursWorked' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final`. Any ideas how to do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
        calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText hourlyWageNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourlyWageNum);
                EditText hoursWorkedNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hoursWorkedNum);
                TextView resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
                Switch overtimeSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.overtimeSwitch);

                double hourlyWage = Double.parseDouble(hourlyWageNum.getText().toString());
                double hoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(hoursWorkedNum.getText().toString());
                double preTax;

                overtimeSwitch.setChecked(true);
                overtimeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                        if(isChecked){
                            if(hoursWorked > 40){
                                preTax = (40 * hourlyWage) + ((hoursWorked - 40) * hourlyWage * 1.5); // these variables
                            } else{
                                preTax = hourlyWage * hoursWorked; // these variables
                            }
                        }else{
                            preTax = hourlyWage * hoursWorked; // these variables
                        }
                    }
                });

                double postTax = preTax - preTax * 0.076;
                NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                resultText.setText(formatter.format(postTax));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve with the switch button is to compute the pretax if the switch is on. Instead of setting the switch's listener on calcButton click listener you should compute the pretax inside it if the switch is on. See sample code below, I also made some minor changes to make the logic shorter.

Replace this one:

```
  overtimeSwitch.setChecked(true);
  overtimeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
          if(isChecked){
              if(hoursWorked > 40){
                  preTax = (40 * hourlyWage) + ((hoursWorked - 40) * hourlyWage * 1.5); // these variables
              } else{
                  preTax = hourlyWage * hoursWorked; // these variables
              }
         }else{
             preTax = hourlyWage * hoursWorked; // these variables
         }
      }
 });
```

With this.

```
double pretax = 0.0;
Boolean isSwitchOn = overtimeSwitch.isChecked();

if (isSwitchOn && hoursWorked > 40) { // compute the pretax
    preTax = (40 * hourlyWage) + ((hoursWorked - 40) * hourlyWage * 1.5);
} else {
   preTax = hourlyWage * hoursWorked;
}
```

Comment: Ya wow that was actually perfect. New to this stuff so its nice to see how to do things in an easier way lol. They way I did it, the output was always 0 until I had already hit calculate then turned the switch on. Idk why that was

Comment: Based on your origninal code, I think the recalculation won't trigger again even turning the switch one after hitting the calculate button. Because all of the logic for calculation is tied in the calculation button. And also, if you really want to put some action on change of the switch, you may set its handler inside the scope of onCreate method, then you may also move the variables to calculate the value to the scope of the class, so that you'll make it as an instance variables of your MainActivity class. In that way you'll have more control over it.